# nodemailer not sending attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer to send a mail along with attachments. But before sending attachments i need to verify  if it exists, for that reason i'm assigning it to a variable. But when i'm using the variable its not sending the attachment

> working

```
smtpTransport.sendMail({
            from: data_to_send.from,
            to: data_to_send.to,
            subject: data_to_send.subject,
            atachments: data_to_send.attachments,
            text: data_to_send.text,
            html: data_to_send.html,
            attachments: [{
                filename: 'file1' + file1ext,
                filePath: file1Path 
            }, {
                filename: 'file2' + file2ext, 
                filePath: file2Path 

            }],
        }
.....
```

> not working

```
 data_to_send.attachments = [{
    filename: 'file1' + file1ext, //"file1.jpg",
    filePath: file1Path //'uploads/file1.jpg'
}, {
    filename: 'file2' + file2ext, //"file2.jpg",
    filePath: file2Path //'uploads/file2.jpg'
}];

console.log(data_to_send.attachments)
smtpTransport.sendMail({
        from: data_to_send.from,
        to: data_to_send.to,
        subject: data_to_send.subject,
        atachments: data_to_send.attachments,
        text: data_to_send.text,
        html: data_to_send.html,
        attachments: data_to_send.attachments
    },
....
```

Comment: So, what do you say?

Answer (score 1):

Two errors:

1. You have two lines supposedly doing the same thing. Remove this line (there's a typo and it's duplicated):

   ```
   atachments: data_to_send.attachments,
   ```
2. Change `filePath` to *`path`* — [check the docs](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#attachments), and [this issue](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/492)

   ```
   data_to_send.attachments = [{
     filename: 'file1' + file1ext,
     path: file1Path
   }, {
     filename: 'file2' + file2ext,
     path: file2Path
   }];
   ```